# Django django-admin-tools DashboardModule - HTML Content

Tags: python, django, django-admin

The [django-admin-tools](http://readthedocs.org/docs/django-admin-tools/en/v0.3.0/dashboard.html) says, we can use HTML (or) Text in the children. But It's escaping the given HTML Tags. All the tags have been displayed as given without rendering.

```
self.children.append(modules.DashboardModule(
                  title = 'Example',
                  children = ['<b>bold example</b>',],
))
```

Comment: The example contains 'children' attribute but the question is about 'pre_content' attribute, this is a bit confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit the template

> admin_tools/dashboard/module.html

and add

> {% autoescape off %} {% endautoescape
>   %}

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
pre_content
Text or HTML content to display above the module content. Default value: None.

content
The module text or HTML content. Default value: None.

post_content
Text or HTML content to display under the module content. Default value: None.
```

No where in that whole document does it say that the `children` property can contain HTML.

Comment: content is nothing but list of children

Comment: @Siva, all the examples in the documentation deal with assigning a list of Module type objects to the children property. You are assigning a list of strings. Having to edit the templates provided by this module seems incorrect to me. Have you tried creating the children property with the types provided by this module?